# not able to fetch JSONP data from my own api in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, python-2.7, jsonp

I am trying to fetch data from my own api but was not able to succeed in fetching the same to vegdata variable... here is the controller code

```
    $scope.filterText = null;
$scope.vegdata =[];
$scope.init = function() {
url = "http://192.168.1.17\:5000/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.vegdata = data;  


    }).error(function(errord){
      alert(errord);
    });
```

JSOn format looks like below... the same I was able to fetch through browser

```
[{"name": "Tuar", "image": "0.0", "fat": "0.0", "alias": [{"vegname": "Tuar ", "language": "Hindi"}, {"vegname": "Red Gram", "language": "English"}, {"vegname": "Cajanus cajan", "language": "Botanical Name"}], "protein": "0.0", "energy": "0.0", "carbohydrates": "0.0"}]
```

Comment: Is there any console error? Please provide more information.

Comment: Is it a typo in the url `http://192.168.1.17\:5000`? It should be `http://192.168.1.17:5000`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies... I tried  "http://192.168.1.17:5000?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"; also no luck            ; There were no error in console... no data being shown in page

Comment: Did you use a network sniffer to see what is being sent and returned?

Answer (score 2):

Your response should be like this:

```
yourCallBack([{"name": "Tuar", "image": "0.0", "fat": "0.0", "alias": [{"vegname": "Tuar ", "language": "Hindi"}, {"vegname": "Red Gram", "language": "English"}, {"vegname": "Cajanus cajan", "language": "Botanical Name"}], "protein": "0.0", "energy": "0.0", "carbohydrates": "0.0"}]);
```

With `yourCallBack` being retrieved from **callback** query string. I don't know how to do it with python, in asp.net mvc I would to something like this:

```
string callback = Request.QueryString["callback"];
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  Using AngularJS's JSONP function; the JSONP callback function ( JSON_CALLBACK ) is handled by the Angular framework and you do not need to create an explicit function to handle it.

Comment: @Reboog711: I mean the data returned from server side must be wrapped.

Comment: @Reboog711: `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` will be turned into something like `callback=angular.callbacks._0.` by angular. On server side, we have to take this callback from the query string and wrap the response

Comment: Oh, you're right.  My mistake; I removed the downvote.