# jsonp call not returning data in angular?

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to return data through a JSONP call from my angular application. I tried this workaround: [angular $resource with jsonp not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267285/angular-resource-with-jsonp-not-working).  All I did was replacing it for my webapi link and suddenly the callback 'blaat' is not triggered? fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/QC4Wk/5/
This is a fragment of the code:

```
$http({
            method: "JSONP",
            params: {
                callback: "blaat"
            },
            url: "http://localhost:7234/api/person",
            isArray: true
})
```

My ApiController looks like:

```
 public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        public List<Person> Get()
        {
            Person person1 = new Person() { name = "mark", id = 1 };
            Person person2 = new Person() { name = "ed", id = 2 };
            Person person3 = new Person() { name = "fred", id = 3 };

            List<Person> lijst = new List<Person>();
            lijst.Add(person1);
            lijst.Add(person2);
            lijst.Add(person3);

            return lijst;
        }
}
```

How can I wrap the callback on the serverside properly so I can use this in the angularrequest?

Comment: did you wrap your data on server inside the callback? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967872/not-able-to-fetch-jsonp-data-from-my-own-api-in-angularjs/21968050#21968050

Comment: I put in "blaat" as a callback parameter but it does not wrap it?

Comment: You have to modify your server code to support jsonp by wrapping the response inside the callback.

Comment: I am using asp.net web api see edit

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-asp-net-web-api .

Comment: tried this got errors there, Khanh do you have a node.js web api sample server maybe?

Comment: what errors do you get? That should be the solution, maybe there are some mistakes