# AngularJS $http.jsonp request fail

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I've written an ajax call to a large json file who need authentication.

```
 var responsePromise = $http.jsonp("http://url_to_file/file.json", 
                                      {headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)}});

 responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Success")
 });
 responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("AJAX failed!");
 });
```

When checking the Network tab in the chrome developer tool I can see the request succeed with status 200, But the promise objec still cactched in the error callback:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you wrap your server response inside the callback? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967872/not-able-to-fetch-jsonp-data-from-my-own-api-in-angularjs/21968050#21968050

Comment: I don't have any control of the responding server

Comment: if the server does not support jsonp, we cannot do it

Comment: What the alternative I have to pull the json from the remote server?

Comment: check if the server supports CORS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing